# MS sql inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables one is **Subjects** and **UserDetails**  Columns of those two tables:

- `Subjects`(RegNo,IndexNo,Subject_1,Subject_23,Subject_3,Subject_4) and
- `UserDetails`(Name,DOB,RegNo,Address,ID)

I want to get `Name`,`DOB`,`RegNo`, `Address`, `ID` from `UserDetails` and **Index** from Subjects acoording to a specific subject .i created a query but it is not working _subject is the string variable which contains the subject name

```
SELECT UserDetails.Name,UserDetails.DOB,
      UserDetails.RegNo,UserDetails.Address, UserDetails.ID,
Subjects.IndexNo 
FROM UserDetails
INNER JOIN Subjects  ON UserDetails.RegNo = Subjects.RegNo 
WHERE Subjects Subject_1 
   OR Subject_2 
   OR Subject_3 OR Subject_4 ='"+_subject+"'"
```

Comment: I don't know MS SQL, but the "where" part it's not convincing me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably figure this out on your own, but you need to specify each part of the WHERE clause, like this:

```
WHERE Subjects.Subject_1 = '"+_subject+"'"
OR Subjects.Subject_2 = '"+_subject+"'"
OR Subjects.Subject_3 = '"+_subject+"'"
OR Subjects.Subject_4 = '"+_subject+"'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your where clause is invalid.

Try

```
WHERE
   Subject_1 = '"+_subject+"' 
   OR Subject_2 = '"+_subject+"'
   OR Subject_3 = '"+_subject+"'
   OR Subject_4 = '"+_subject+"'"
```

I'm assuming that your _subject string has been sanitized and that a user couldn't just use it for a SQL injection attack ...

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to match any of the subjects  for UserDetails against a string stored in a variable?

Try this

```
DECLARE @subject varchar(20) = 'subjectstringvalue'; --variables are declared like this in T-sql
SELECT
ud.Name
,ud.DOB
,ud.RegNo
,ud.Address
,ud.ID
,s.IndexNo 

FROM UserDetails AS ud
INNER JOIN Subjects AS s
    ON ud.RegNo = s.RegNo 

WHERE s.Subject_1 = @subject --variables are used like this in T-sql
OR Subject_2 = @subject
OR Subject_3 = @subject
OR Subject_4 = @subject
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead just create a simple stored procedure like below and pass your subject value as parameter.

```
CREATE PROC GetDetails
(
    @Subject VARCHAR(10)
)
BEGIN       
    SELECT UserDetails.Name,UserDetails.DOB,
          UserDetails.RegNo,UserDetails.Address, UserDetails.ID,
    Subjects.IndexNo 
    FROM UserDetails
    INNER JOIN Subjects  ON UserDetails.RegNo = Subjects.RegNo 
    WHERE Subject_1 = @Subject 
       OR Subject_2 = @Subject
       OR Subject_3 = @Subject
END
```